# Google analytics tracking code error in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-analytics

my google analytics tracking code looks like this (it's copy/paste from their website)

```
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
            (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

I get this console error: 
**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var (highlighting last _gat variable)**

```
    var urchinTracker = function() {},
  _gaq = {
    push: function() {
      try {
        if (arguments[0][0] == '_link') window.location.href = arguments[0][1]
      } catch (er) {}
    }
  },
  _gat = {
    _createTracker: function() {},
    _getTracker: function() {
      return {
        __noSuchMethod__: function() {},
        _link: function(o) {
          if (o) location.href = o;
        },
        _linkByPost: function() {
          return true;
        },
        _getLinkerUrl: function(o) {
          return o;
        },
        _trackEvent: function() {}
      }
    }
  };
cxApi = {
  setCookiePath: function() {},
  chooseVariation: function() {}
}
var _gat = {
  _getTrackerByName: function() {
    _trackEvent: function() {}
  }
};
```

this seems to happen only in chrome?

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually seems to be an issue with Ghostery intercepting the request for the analytics.js from Google and returning back some outdated javascript instead, encoded as base64 ([see this comment](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/issues/1170#issuecomment-168946394)). If I uninstall Ghostery, this issue goes away--I'm still running uBlock Origin, but not Ghostery, too.

Answer (score -2):

You need to replace `_gat =` to `_gat :` on line 9